# How to implement PKCE flow in custom external authentication provider?

Tags: single-sign-on, auth-provider, authproviderpluginclass, pkce

Objective is to implement PKCE (proof key for code exchange ) verification as part of SSO with an external identity provider and Salesforce Experience Cloud

**Tried so far:** 
Setup a custom Auth. Provider with a custom authentication provider class (which uses a custom metadata type as per doc [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_provider_plugin_custom.htm&type=5)) and followed steps provided in the answer [How to implement PKCE flow in Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/330173) to generate the `code_challenge` from `code_verifier`.

**Result**
HTTP callout response gives error `Invalid parameter: code_verifier` in `handlecallback` method.

Debug logs shows that `initiate` and `handleCallback` method are executed in 2 separate transactions, which is the most probably the reason why `code_verifier` is never the same in `handleCallback`.

***Tried these other options knowing that none of them is secure even if it worked* :**
1/ Added logic in `initiate` method to save the `code_verifier` in a platform session cache but the current user session id is always null, so data cannot be saved

2/ Saved the `code_verifier` value in a hierarchical custom settings but field came up as empty in `handleCallback` method

**Question:** 
So how to perform PKCE verification in a custom authentication provider class ?

Here is the relevant code for custom authentication provider class :

```java
global with sharing class CustomAuthProvider extends Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass {
    private String customMetadataTypeApiName = 'CustomAuth__mdt'; 
    public  String redirectUrl; 
    private String key;
    private String secret;
    private String authUrl;  
    private String accessTokenUrl; 
    private String userInfoUrl; 
    private String scope;
    String codeVerifier  = generateRandomString(34);
    Blob sha256          = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', Blob.valueOf(codeVerifier));
    String codeChallenge = base64URLencode(sha256);
    
    global String getCustomMetadataType(){
        return customMetadataTypeApiName;
    }

    private static String base64URLencode(Blob input){
        String output = encodingUtil.base64Encode(input);
        output = output.replace('+', '-');
        output = output.replace('/', '_');
        while ( output.endsWith('=')){
            output = output.subString(0,output.length()-1);
        }
        return output;
    }
    
    private static String generateRandomString(Integer len) {
        final String chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        String randStr = '';
        while (randStr.length() < len) {
            Integer idx = Math.mod(Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger()), chars.length());
            randStr += chars.substring(idx, idx+1);
        }
        return randStr; 
    }

    global PageReference initiate(Map<string,string> authProviderConfiguration, String stateToPropagate) { 

        key         = authProviderConfiguration.get('ConsumerKey__c');
        authUrl     = authProviderConfiguration.get('AuthURL__c');
        scope       = authProviderConfiguration.get('Scope__c');
        redirectUrl = authProviderConfiguration.get('CallbackURL__c');

        String urlToRedirect = authUrl+'?client_id='+key+'&response_type=code&redirect_uri='+redirectUrl+'&state='+stateToPropagate
                                +'&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge='+codeChallenge;

        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(urlToRedirect);
        return pageRef;
    } 
    
    global Auth.AuthProviderTokenResponse handleCallback(Map<string,string> authProviderConfiguration, Auth.AuthProviderCallbackState state ) { 
        key = authProviderConfiguration.get('ConsumerKey__c'); 
        secret = authProviderConfiguration.get('ConsumerSecret__c'); 
        accessTokenUrl = authProviderConfiguration.get('TokenURL__c'); 
        redirectUrl = authProviderConfiguration.get('CallbackURL__c');
        
        Map<String,String> queryParams = state.queryParameters; 
        String code = queryParams.get('code'); 
        String sfdcState = queryParams.get('state'); 

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
        String requestBody = 'grant_type=authorization_code&client_id='+key+'&client_secret='+secret+'&code='+code
                             +'&redirect_uri='+redirectUrl+'&state='+sfdcState +'&code_verifier='+codeVerifier;
        req.setEndpoint(accessTokenUrl); 
        req.setHeader('Accept','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
        req.setMethod('POST'); 
        req.setBody(requestBody);
        Http http = new Http(); 
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req); //Invalid parameter: code_verifier error here
        
        String responseBody = res.getBody(); 
        System.debug(SYSTEM.LoggingLevel.DEBUG, '\n **** responseBody '+responseBody); 
        
        return new Auth.AuthProviderTokenResponse('CustomAuthProvider', null, null, sfdcState); 
    } 
   
               
    global Auth.UserData getUserInfo(Map<string,string> authProviderConfiguration, Auth.AuthProviderTokenResponse response) { 
       ///getUserInfo
    }     

}
```

Comment: @identigral Do you have any insight on this topic ?

Comment: Try using org-wide cache with a key that uniquely identifies this request

Comment: @identigral noted, will try this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***For anyone finding this thread later and trying todo the same.***

Me and a college implemented this for Experience Cloud just a few months ago.
Initially we tried using a custom object to store and retrieve code_challenge, but we where unable to retrieve this records in the handleCallback method due to DML issues.

We then opted for saving it in the org-wide PlatformCache.
It's worth mentioning that the key length is quite short. So you would need to find a way to get a unique key that is both in the initiated and in the handleCallback method. *As you saw this are in to different transactions*. We opted for using the state provided by salesforce, but shortened it down with the method below:

```java
public string getSessionId(String state) {    
  return base64URLencode(
   Crypto.generateDigest('SHA1', Blob.valueOf(state))
  )      
  .remove('_')      
  .remove('-');  
}
```

Using the PlatformCache also had some issues, but got recently resolved here: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000smXe9/sso-failing-with-no_oauth_state-error-code-with-custom-auth-provider

**Example Implementation**

Implement a PlatformCache class that is responsible of storing and retriving from the org-partion. You can take inspiration from  [PlatformCacheRecipies class from Apex-Recipies repo](https://github.com/trailheadapps/apex-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/classes/Platform%20Cache%20Recipes/PlatformCacheRecipes.cls).
Here you only would only need the methods `storeValueInOrgCache` and `getValueFromOrgCache`.
Then setup your own platform cache partiton in setup. You might find [this video helpful on the platform cache setup](https://youtu.be/IGlPBBFJUwQ?t=361) by [Matt Gerry](https://www.linkedin.com/in/mattgerry/).

In your custom auth provider class that extends Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass you will need to create the `code_challenge` and `code_verifier` in the initiate method.

```java
public PageReference initiate(
  Map<String, String> config,
  String stateToPropagate
) {
  String sessionId = this.getSessionId(stateToPropagate);
  String codeChallenge = this.getCodeChallenge(
    // CODE_VERIFIER_LENGTH can be set to eg. 64
    this.getCodeVerifier(CODE_VERIFIER_LENGTH, sessionId),
    sessionId
  );
  // Create your authorizationUrl
  return new PageReference(authorizationUrl);
}
```

The getCodeVerifier should return `code_verifier` or create, store and return `code_verifier` depending on if it is called from initiate method or handleCallback.

```java
public String getCodeVerifier(Integer length, String sessionId) {
  String key = 'codeVerifier' + sessionId;
    // return codeVerifier from cache if found
    this.codeVerifier = PlatformCache.getValueFromOrgCache(key);
    if (String.isNotBlank(this.codeVerifier)) {
      return this.codeVerifier;
    }
    // generate new code verifier in the pattern you like. 
    // Here represented by randStr.
      this.codeVerifier = randStr;
      PlatformCache.storeValueInOrgCache(key, this.codeVerifier, TIME_TO_LIVE);
  return this.codeVerifier;
}
```

The getCodeChallenge is only needed in the initiate method so there should be no need to store this in the cache.

```java
public String getCodeChallenge(String codeVerifier, String sessionId) {
  return this.base64URLencode(
        Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', Blob.valueOf(this.codeVerifier))
      );
}
```

The base64URLencode is used both in getSessionId and getCodeChallenge

```java
private String base64URLencode(Blob oneWayHash) {
  String output = encodingUtil.base64Encode(oneWayHash);
  // Remove unsupported characters to be able to store in cache.
  output = output.replace('+', '-');
  output = output.replace('/', '_');
  while (output.endsWith('=')) {
    output = output.subString(0, output.length() - 1);
  }
  return output;
}
```

To cleanup our work with the platform cache i would recommend to remove any used code_verifiers or code_challenge at the end or the handleCallback method. It will also be removed automatically based on the seconds set in TIME_TO_LIVE.

Tip: We used Nebula logger with platform events to debug this as DML behaviour was limited in custom Auth.Provider https://github.com/jongpie/NebulaLogger

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I will look into this later. 
could you also provide the minimum code snippet showing how you are saving the code_challenge in the platform cache

Comment: No problem @Shamina! Have updated my initial comment with example methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot Erlend for taking the time to update the answer, much appreciated